# DB2 database restore

Tags: db2, db2-luw

When I am restoring the database, by default data is going in C drive, but when I installed the db2 that time I specify the path in D drive only.
Also, sample database files created by db2 is stored in D drive.
Can anyone please tell me what is the issue?

I have run this command:

```
SELECT * FROM SYSIBMADM.DBPATHS
```

below is the result i fetched:

```
LOGPATH- D:\DB2\NODE000\SQL00001\SQLOGDIR\
DB_STORAGE_PATH- C:\
LOCAL_DB_DIRECTORY -  D:\DB2\NODE000\SQLOGDIR\
DBPATH - D:\DB2\NODE000\SQL00001\
```

I Want to change this `DB_STORAGE_PATH` C:\ to D:\ for all the database which i will be restoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run db2set from db2 command line that will confirm you wheather db2 installed on path with other information;

```
db2-command-line> db2set

DB2_ATS_ENABLE=YES
DB2_CREATE_DB_ON_PATH=YES
DB2INSTPROF=C:\where\db2\installed\IBM\DB2\DB2COPY1
DB2COMM=TCPIP
```

You can get more information of [Directory structure for your installed DB2 database product (Windows)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/r0024442.html) here

You can run the following command `SELECT * FROM SYSIBMADM.DBPATHS`. This will give details of following variables of your installed db2 database;

- LOGPATH
- DB_STORAGE_PATH
- LOCAL_DB_DIRECTORY
- DBPATH

These commands will provide you enough information to locate your installed database. Then you can restore your database providing the exact path.

To add a storage path to an existing database, issue the following ALTER DATABASE statement:

```
ALTER DATABASE database-name ADD STORAGE ON storage-path
```

After adding one or more storage paths to the database, you may use the ALTER TABLESPACE statement to rebalance table spaces in the database so that they start to use the new storage paths immediately.

Comment: I have updated my question now, using your solution. can u pls check again?

Comment: @Govind I have edited the answer based on your changed question.

Comment: you didn't get my question, i mean to say that whenever i restore a database that time it should go in D drive itself at the time of restore. so how do i change this by default storage setting?

Comment: You have to use `REDIRECT`. This article will explain - https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/AllAboutData/entry/backup_a_db2_database_and_restore_redirect_it_to_a_different_location?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

DB2 has a configuration parameter for the default path for databases, [dftdbpath](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0000281.html). In addition, the command [db2sampl](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001934.html) to create a sample database has an option `dbpath` to specify where to place that database.

```
db2sample -dbpath D:
```

The above would place the new database on drive `D:`.

You will find that there are default paths for certain operations. The overview of [DB2 database manager configuration parameters](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/c0060794.html) has lists most of them.

For your specific issue I would assume that a parameter was changed some time after DB2 was installed and used initially.

For [RESTORE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001976.html) be aware that the options `TO` and `DBPATH` are ignored if restoring an existing database.

Comment: Its not working, actually when i am restoring the database, it is placing data on C:\DB2\NODE0000 location, but i want to store it D:\DB2\NODE0000 location.

Comment: RESTORE DATABASE CH_APR FROM "D:\DB Backup" TAKEN AT 20170317105344 TO "D:" INTO CH_APR WITH 2 BUFFERS BUFFER 1024 PARALLELISM 1 WITHOUT PROMPTING;

Comment: I added more details, but you are mixing at least 2 issues with your question.

Comment: What about db2sampl? Did you use the option I provided?

Comment: No Actually I am not talking about sample database. you just consider CH_APR database which i want to store in D drive but it is taking space in C drive